# Is the product of sub-Gaussian polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n-1)$ sub-Gaussian?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, orlicz-spaces

Let $\psi_\alpha(x) := \exp(x^\alpha)-1$.
It is well-known that for $\alpha\geq 1$ that

$$\lVert X\rVert_{\psi_\alpha} = \inf\{k>0\mid \mathbb{E}[\psi_\alpha(|X|/k)] \leq 1\}$$

defines an [Orlicz norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz_space) on the space of random variables.
The norm for $\alpha = 2$ is known as the sub-Gaussian norm, and $\alpha = 1$ is known as the sub-Exponential norm.
It is also known that $\lVert XY\rVert_{\psi_1} \leq \lVert X\rVert_{\psi_2}\lVert Y\rVert_{\psi_2}$ (perhaps up to an absolute constant), e.g. one may control the sub-Exponential norm of a product via the sub-Gaussian norm of the product-ands.
For random vectors, one defines

$$\lVert \vec X\rVert_{\psi_a} = \sup_{\theta : \lVert \theta\rVert_{2} = 1} \lVert \langle \vec X, \theta\rangle\rVert_{\psi_a}.$$

---

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution of finite sub-Gaussian norm on $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n-1)\cong \mathbb{R}^n$, where the isomorphism is the mapping of coefficients of polynomials to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I am curious about what one can say about $\lVert f(x)g(x)\rVert_{\psi_a}$.

By noticing that any particular coordinate of $f(x)g(x)$ is the sum of $n$ products of independent sub-Gaussian random variables, it is straightforward to get the estimate

$$\lVert f(x)g(x)\rVert_{\psi_1}\leq n\lVert f(x)\rVert_{\psi_2}\lVert g(x)\rVert_{\psi_2}.$$

I am curious if you can do better somehow.
For example, if $\mathcal{D}$ is not solely sub-Gaussian, but is the product of $n$ 1D independent sub-Gaussian random variables, then any particular coordinate of $f(x)g(x)$ is the sum of $n$ independent random variables.
One would expect that for large $n$ this will (by the CLT) approach a Gaussian, and therefore would have Gaussian-like tails.

Can this be formalized/made quantitative at all, via some bound on $\lVert f(x)g(x)\rVert_{\psi_2}$? Or (in general) via some stronger Orlicz-norm bound on $f(x)g(x)$ than the above $\psi_1$ bound?

Answer (score 1):

I had known that

> Or (in general) via some stronger Orlicz-norm bound on $f(x)g(x)$
> than the above $\psi_1$ bound?

was plausibly related to the [Bennett-Orlicz norm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01721.pdf) (or perhaps [Bernstein-Orlicz norm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2450.pdf)), but these papers only really talked about concentration bounds on the *suprema* $\sup_i |X_i|$ of vectors, rather than bounds on the *sum* $S_n := \sum_i X_i$ of vectors.

Looking more though, it looks like Corollary 1 of [Improved Concentration Bounds for sums of Independent Sub-Exponential Random Variables](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.06037.pdf) gives me what I want, though as the exposition of it makes it sound like I plausibly could have gotten what I wanted from the Bernstein-Orlicz norm paper if I was more familiar with the standard arguments of this area.